# How to remove a section from a typesafe config object?

Tags: configuration, typesafe

How do I remove a section from typesafe config?

Below is a simplified problem -

```
import com.typesafe.config.{ConfigFactory, Config}

val configStr: String = """{
  section1 {
    s1Val1 = "a"
  }
  section2 {
    s2Val1 = "b"
  }
}"""

val overrideConfigStr : String = """{
  section2 {
    s2Val2 = "bPrime"
  }
}"""

val myConfig : Config = ConfigFactory.parseString(configStr)

def removeConfigSection(config: Config, sectionHead: String): Config = ???

val overrideConfig : Config = ConfigFactory.parseString(overrideConfigStr)

val newConfigWithOverride = removeConfigSection(myConfig, 
      "section2").withFallback(overrideConfig)
```

Like the case for "section2", I want to take a *big* config file and override many sections with some custom sections. How do I implement def removeConfigSection(config: Config, sectionHead: String)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`withoutPath()`](https://lightbend.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/Config.html#withoutPath-java.lang.String-):

`def removeConfigSection(config: Config, sectionHead: String): Config = 
  config.withoutPath(sectionHead)`

Just make sure to take care of proper quoting of `path`.